# Force ask authorization onOpen() (force popup)

Tags: google-apps-script, permissions, google-sheets, authorization

**SUMMARY: Is it possible to ask for authorization onOpen()?**

DETAILED VERSION:
I have a spreadsheet with buttons that gets distributed to a lot of people.
When any button is pressed, some functions that require permissions are called, so Google Apps Script shows this popup:

[image]

AFTER this is accepted, everything runs well, since it has authorization now. However, I want to run things that require permissions BEFORE a button is pushed, when the Workbook is opened. However, if you place authorization-requiring code into an onEdit or onOpen function, it runs with no privileges by default and crashes halfway, rather than showing the popup and asking for permissions.

Here is some code that exemplifies this - crashing instead of asking for permissions to create a trigger (also works for CalendarApp, etc.):

```
function onOpen(e) {
  Browser.msgBox("This is shown to the user");
  try {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('someFunction').forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()).onEdit().create();
  }
  catch (e) {
    Browser.msgBox(e);
  }
  Browser.msgBox("This message is never shown to the user if there is no try catch because it crashes");
}
```

Comment: There is 2 possible solutions, multiple installable triggers or using of temporaryActiveUserKey:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77454609/17137584

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note:  A simple trigger cannot access services that require authorization. For example, a simple trigger cannot send an email because the Gmail service requires authorization

`onOpen()` is a reserved function name for a function that is a simple trigger.

There is a way to check the authorization status, and then get the authorization URL if the code needs to be authorized.  However, if the `ScriptApp.getAuthorizationInfo(ScriptApp.AuthMode.FULL)` method needs authorization by the user, then it won't work when run from `onOpen()`

The `onOpen` method can not open a sidebar, so the authorization status can't be checked from the `onOpen` trigger.  The user would need to click a menu item that opened the sidebar or a dialog box first.

I'm not sure that the code 'ScriptApp.getAuthorizationInfo(ScriptApp.AuthMode.FULL)` works that well.  To force a re-authorization prompt, you may need to run code that would cause the scopes to be evaluated.

### Code.gs

```
function onOpen() {
  //Create custom menu or add-on menu
}

function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('HTML_Sidebar').evaluate()
      .setTitle('Log Tools')
      .setWidth(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
      .showSidebar(html);
}
```

### HTML_Sidebar

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_blank">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div><?!= getAuthUrl(); ?></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

### GS_Sidebar

```
function getAuthUrl() {
  var authInfo,msg;

  authInfo = ScriptApp.getAuthorizationInfo(ScriptApp.AuthMode.FULL);

  msg = 'This spreadsheet needs permission to use Apps Script Services.  Click ' +
    'this url to authorize: <br><br>' + 
      '<a href="' + authInfo.getAuthorizationUrl() +
      '">Link to Authorization Dialog</a>' +      
      '<br><br> This spreadsheet needs to either ' +
      'be authorized or re-authorized.';

  //return msg;//Use this for testing

  //ScriptApp.AuthMode.FULL is the auth mode to check for since no other authorization mode requires
  //that users grant authorization
  if (authInfo.getAuthorizationStatus() === ScriptApp.AuthorizationStatus.REQUIRED) {
    return msg;
  } else {
    return "No Authorization needed";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the information.  There is an ongoing issue with scripts sometimes loosing their authorization.  If a script looses its authorization, then it will fail.  Although I've had situations where an authorization error causes my code to fail, but it still sends me an error message with `UrlFetchApp.fetch(my url)`  So, I don't really understand what is exactly happening.

Comment: The ongoing issue was clarified: On 2018 Google added restrictions to simple triggers.

Comment: Sidebar can't be opened with simple triggers any more.

Answer (score 4):

Nowadays it's not always possible to force ask authorization onOpen as Google made some policy changes that now prevent that script automatically open an UI element by using a simple trigger like `onOpen`.

This could be possible for the owner of the spreadsheet but not for editors.

From [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50470597/1595451) (almost one year old, 0 votes so far) to [onOpen not executing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50383296/1595451)

> A simple trigger open function can't open a sidebar because it runs on
>   AuthMode.LIMITED. You should use a function that runs on 
>   Auth.Mode.FULL to open a sidebar, like an installable trigger.
>
> I know that this isn't about add-ons but the following quote applies
>
> From
>   https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/lifecycle#authorization_modes
>
> > Note: Add-ons can't open sidebars or dialogs while executing in AuthMode.LIMITED. You can use menu items to open sidebars and dialogs
> >     since these run in AuthMode.FULL.
>
> The cannonical references are
>
> - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/
> - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events