# onOpen not executing?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi guys im trying to display a sidebar on my google sheets every time it is opened. I am using the onOpen function and calling the html page, but it is not executing. When i run the function manually it works, however it doesnt execute on its own when the google sheet is opened. 
Here is my code:

```
.gs code: 

function onOpen(){
       var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('tipA')
      .setWidth(300);
       SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .showSidebar(html); 
}

.html code: 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div>
   <p> Some text <p> 
   <p><img src="some link" alt="xyz" width=240 height=210></p>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you say "running the function manually" do you mean using a browser debugger to run it (like chrome debugger?)? Can you give more context into what you would like to achieve?

Comment: @TranTriet By "running it manually" i mean, when i go to Tools> script editor , i am able to select a specific function and run it there to test it. What i want to achieve is, when an end user opens my spreadsheet, i want a sidebar to show with some text on it.

Answer (score 1):

A simple trigger open function can't open a sidebar because it runs on AuthMode.LIMITED. You should use a function that runs on  Auth.Mode.FULL to open a sidebar, like an installable trigger.

I know that this isn't about add-ons but the following quote applies

From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/lifecycle#authorization_modes

> Note: Add-ons can't open sidebars or dialogs while executing in AuthMode.LIMITED. You can use menu items to open sidebars and dialogs since these run in AuthMode.FULL.

The cannonical references are

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

Answer (score 1):

Google has (quite) recently restricted the functionality of onOpen triggers.
One of the restrains is the impossibility to show a sidebar.
There is no real workaround since installable triggers will only work for the user that created the trigger, not for the other users.
Instead you will receive a error notification each time someone opens the document.
The best solution I found is to create a button that one can use to open the sidebar, this is easier than a menu and obviously more visible.
There is a referenced issue on that subject : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69238694

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the user doesn't have permission to edit the SS? [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) says onOpen() only fires if the user who is visiting your sheet has permission to edit the SS.

Comment: Your Browser doesn't have JavaScript deactivated?

Answer (score 0):

See if this works

```
function showSideBar() {
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .showSidebar(HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('tipA')
        .evaluate()
        .setTitle('Some title'));
}
```

and use an installable onOpen trigger on this function.
As the previous poster already mentioned, I also don't believe you can show a sidebar (which requires authorization) on a simple onOpen trigger (which doesn't require authorization).

Comment: if i run this manually from the script editor, it works. However, when i refresh the spreadsheet page, the sidebar is not showing.

Comment: Try renaming the function (see updated answer) and use an installable onopen trigger.

Comment: can installable onOpen triggers run automatically? and if i set it up will all the users see it?