# onOpen event does not not launch a dialog box

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a sheet that I send out to staff (copies that are shared) but when I copy this the function onOpen does not launch the dialog box.

```
function onOpen() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
}

function openDialog() {
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
    .showModalDialog(html, 'Math Sheet Directions');
}
```

Comment: Are inline comments allowed in this language? You have `object1.object2 // comment .method()`, which may be causing an error.

Comment: Please tag this with the language you are using - JavaScript?

Comment: This is in a google sheet. The script runs for me after I allowed/permissions. However, when I make a copy of the sheet the new sheet will not execute unless permissions are allowed again.

Comment: Ah, OK - so it now works?

Comment: This is by design. Simple triggers are never allowed to display dialogs...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Would you happen to have a suggestion as to how I can have a popup with the ability to display url links and not require permissions when I copy?

Comment: @MICHAELGARBER You could create links in different sheet, onOpen activate it, and for example in 3 seconds activate the main Sheet with Apps Script. Is this option seems interesting to you?

Comment: I'm not sure this solves the issue. I need to be able to have users open their copy and on opening...popup with message and url links

Answer (score 0):

Take a deep look on the next thread : [onOpen not executing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50383296/onopen-not-executing)

As you can see from the thread and *Issue Tracker*:

> Google has restriction for `onOpen` functionality

### Is there a different way to achieve your goal?

- You can create a red button "Show URLs" and assign it a function.

For example:

```js
function openDialogBox() {

  // your html content here
  var html = "<a href='https://google.com'>Google.com</a><br /><a href='https://stackoverflow.com'>Stackoverflow.com</a>" ;

  var htmlOutput = HtmlService
    .createHtmlOutput(html)
    .setWidth(250)
    .setHeight(300);

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'URL links');

}
```

This is how it looks like:

[image: Dialogbox output]

We don't have any restriction here.

I know this method doesn't help you, but probably this is the only way to achieve similar behavior of what you want to do :)

## Reference

- [Google Apps Script - onOpen()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onopene)
- [Google Apps Script - Class HtmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service)
- [Google Apps Script Guide - HTML Service: Create and Serve HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html)