# Google form error: The caller does not have permission at onSubmit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-oauth, google-forms, google-classroom

We use a Google form which is meant to create recurring Classroom assignments through Google Apps Script.
The script runs successfully once a user opens the form in edit mode, as she/he is prompted to authorise script execution scopes.

What is not working is when a generic user is accessing the form to only submit data: in this case there's no prompt to authorise script scopes execution, therefore the `onSubmit` script will run, throwing the following error:

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to classroom.courses.courseWork.create failed with error: The caller does not have permission at onSubmit

Offending code:

```
 var ret = Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.create(ClassSource, course);
```

BTW, we have set all scopes in manifest:

```
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/Rome",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "Classroom",
        "version": "v1",
        "serviceId": "classroom"
      }
    ]
  },
  "oauthScopes": [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.me.readonly",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.profile.emails",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.profile.photos",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.rosters",

  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.me",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.me.readonly",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.students",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.students.readonly"
],
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

I guess this is due to the fact the user is never prompted to authorise..... Is there a way to trigger the authorisation prompt when the form is being opened somehow?
Notice that the script uses multiple functions, and this is not helping triggering permissions authorisation as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56135070/how-to-authorize-scripts-that-trigger-on-events-like-on-form-submit)

Full script code:

```
function onSubmit(){
  var subjects = [
    ['zzzzzzzzzzzz','Y9 - Art 2022-23'],
    ['yyyyyyyyyyyy','Y7 - Computing 2022-23'],
    ['xxxxxxxxxxxx','Y8 - English 2022-23']
    ];

  try{
    var formResponses = FormApp.getActiveForm().getResponses();
    var length = formResponses.length;
    var lastResponse = formResponses[length-1];
    var respondent = lastResponse.getRespondentEmail();
    var course = null;
    var items = lastResponse.getItemResponses();

    for (i in items){
      var item = items[i].getItem();
      var response = items[i].getResponse();
      if (response){
        var title = item.getTitle();
        switch (title){
          case 'Select the course':
            var hwSubject = response;
            var index = indexOf2dArray(subjects,response);
            if (index[0] >=0){
                // we've got the subject, grab course id
                course = subjects[index[0]][0];
            }
            break;          
          case 'Homework title':  
            var hwTitle = response;
            break;
          case 'Instructions':  
            var hwInstructions = response;
            break;
          case 'Begin date':
            var beginTextDate = response;
            break;
          case 'End date':
            var endTextDate = response;
            break;    
          case 'Status':
            var status = (response == "Draft" ? 'DRAFT' : 'PUBLISHED');
            break;             
           case 'Assignment Time slot':
            var timeSlot = response;
            break;              
            }
      }
    } 
    var beginDate = new Date(beginTextDate);
    var endDate = new Date(endTextDate);
    var creationResponse = '';
    if (course && beginDate < endDate){
      while(beginDate <= endDate){
        console.log(beginDate);           
        var dueDate = {
          "year": beginDate.getUTCFullYear(),
          "month": beginDate.getUTCMonth()+1,
          "day": beginDate.getUTCDate()
        } 
        var dueTime = {
          "hours": parseInt(timeSlot.split(':')[0]),
          "minutes": parseInt(timeSlot.split(':')[1]),
          "seconds": 0,
          "nanos": 0
        }

        var ClassSource =  {
          title: hwTitle,
          description: hwInstructions,
          state: status,
          dueDate : dueDate,
          dueTime : dueTime,
          workType: "ASSIGNMENT"
        };

        var ret = Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.create(ClassSource, course);
        creationResponse += `<br> Assignment status <a href="${ret.alternateLink}">${status}</a>, due date:${JSON.stringify(dueDate)}`; 
        
        Utilities.sleep(500);
        var newDate = beginDate.setDate(beginDate.getDate() + 1);
        beginDate = new Date(newDate);
      }// end while
      
      var emailSubject = "** Classroom recurring homework form response";
      var emailBody = `<strong>Recurring assignment creation response</strong><br>Course: ${hwSubject}, begin date: ${beginTextDate}, end date: ${endTextDate} <br/>`; 
      emailBody += '<br><strong>Homework title:</strong> ' + hwTitle;
      emailBody += '<br><strong>Homework instructions:</strong> ' + hwInstructions + '<br><br>'; 

      emailBody +=  `<br/><strong>Status:</strong> ${creationResponse}<br/>`;
      var emailRecipients = respondent;

      doEmail(emailSubject,emailBody,emailRecipients);
    }else{
      var emailSubject = "** Classroom recurring homework form error";
      var emailBody = `<strong>Course not selected or invalide date ranges</strong><br>course: ${course}, begin date: ${beginTextDate}, end date: ${endTextDate} <br/>`;
      var emailRecipients = respondent;

      doEmail(emailSubject,emailBody,emailRecipients);
    }
  }catch(err){
    console.log(err);  
    var emailSubject = "** Classroom recurring homework form error";
    var emailBody = "<strong>This is an automated message.</strong><br/>";
    emailBody +=  `<br/>Could not schedule homework assignment.<br/>`;
    emailBody += `<br/>${err.stack}<br/>`;
    var emailRecipients = respondent;
    
    doEmail(emailSubject,emailBody,emailRecipients); 
  }

}

function indexOf2dArray(array2d, itemtofind) {
    index = [].concat.apply([], ([].concat.apply([], array2d))).indexOf(itemtofind);
                
    // return "false" if the item is not found
    if (index === -1) { return false; }
    
    // Use any row to get the rows' array length
    // Note, this assumes the rows are arrays of the same length
    numColumns = array2d[0].length;
    
    // row = the index in the 1d array divided by the row length (number of columns)
    row = parseInt(index / numColumns);
    
    // col = index modulus the number of columns
    col = index % numColumns;
    
    return [row, col]; 
}

function doEmail(emailSubject, emailBody,emailRecipients){
  MailApp.sendEmail({
      from: Session.getActiveUser().getEmail,  
      to: emailRecipients,
      subject: emailSubject,
      htmlBody: emailBody,
      name: "Our Mailing"
    });
}
```

**EDIT:**

To allow proper operations, not only the user is required to be a Form editor, but the user is required to debug at least once the `onSubmit` script, which will trigger the authorisation process.

I guess this is a Google Forms architecture limitation, since the onSubmit function is run on the server side, defeating any possibility to trigger authorisation on the client side beforehand :-(

Comment: please edit your question and include [example]

Comment: To who ever close voted this as not programming related. You realize that app script counts as programming right?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58371684/1841839 <-- maybe this

Comment: I have added the full script code

Comment: @DalmTo, the manifest I am using was taken from your suggested post